# nginx rewrite location rule

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

My original url on my mamp is
http://localhost:7888/tosfund/view-project.php?pid=2 and I want to use nginx rewrite it to something like this http://localhost:7888/tosfund/view/project/2.

I have problem with also the location so below is my rewrite block.

```
location /tosfund/view-project.php {
    rewrite ^/view/project/(.*)$ /view-project.php?id=$2 last;
}
```

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Sorry, by mistake I edited your rewrite code instead of mine. I have updated my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct, but not the code:
The final `$2` should be always be `$1`, because you only have one regex.

Also, rewrites should go on directories (usually) or root.
So basically, this should work:

```
location / {
    rewrite "^/view/project/(.*)" /view-project.php?id=$1;
}
```

Comment: Are you changing to `location / {` instead of  `location /tosfund/view-project.php {` And do you have other rewrite rules?

Comment: Hi @peixotorms! I got it works now. I used it in location / { and i have full path to have it worked. Can you tell me how to use this one? `rewrite ^/tosfund.com/update/organization(.*)$ /tosfund.com/action.php?id=update-organization;`